# How to generate seo friendly url's with php?

Tags: php, url, seo

I want to make `http://mysite.com/id255/` to `http://mysite.com/gora-beach-inn/`.

My php looks like:

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT id, header
    FROM Article
");


while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
    mysql_query("
        UPDATE Article
        SET seo = '".MakeSeo($data['header'])."'
        WHERE datum = '".$data['datum']."'
    ");
}

//Convert: "åäö" to "aao", "space" to "-", "!?" to "nothing", and all to lower case.
function MakeSeo($string)
{
    ???
}
```

Please help me with the MakeSoe function.

I use moderewrite, so I just need help to generate the url, so I can save them in my database.

Comment: Take a look at the related questions on the right side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To just answer your requirement .. 
here you go ..

```
function makeSeo($text, $limit=75)
    {
      // replace non letter or digits by -
      $text = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);

      // trim
      $text = trim($text, '-');

      // lowercase
      $text = strtolower($text);

      // remove unwanted characters
      $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);

      if(strlen($text) > 70) {
        $text = substr($text, 0, 70);
      } 

      if (empty($text))
      {
        //return 'n-a';
        return time();
      }

      return $text;
    }
```

You can add more filters to clean the url and may be you add some more stuff to get that url a unique.

Note: I am not saying that adding url to the database is the best way. You could achieve the same sort of functionality using other techniques, for example, mod_rewrite.

Comment: Thanks, works fine, except for åäö, the script generates "1253883725" if `$text` contains åäö.

Comment: hmm .. may be this is because it converts anything other than a-z,A-z,0-9 to empty. YOu can try remove 2nd preg_match (//remove unwanted characters and test)

Comment: Replace the `70` with `$limit` to get the limit to work

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use [mod_rewrite](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite) to achieve this, otherwise the other approach is the 'internal' method done by php, where you would do something similar to:

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php/category/dogs
```

the above is just a GET post, and index handles the content loading via includes / mysql etc;

Answer (score 0):

Non regular expression and more flexible solution can be done via 2 arrays. Define all charcters in *from* and *to* arrays. Omitted characters will be than replaced by -
This is example of javascript function

```
function ToSeoFriendly(title) {
  title = title.toLowerCase();
  var generated = "";
  var from = "ãàáäâẽèéëêìíïîõòóöôùúüûñçýčšžřľňäôabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
  var to   = "aaaaaeeeeeiiiiooooouuuuncycszrlnaoabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890-";
  for (var i=0;i<title.length;i++){
    generated += to.substr(from.indexOf(title.substr(i,1)),1);
  }
  return generated;
}
```