# Sanitizing urls using php for seo friendly

Tags: php, url, seo

I am in the process of turning my urls seo friendly.

My urls for my blog currently look like:

```
http://domain.com/news/view-article.php?id=23+category=qrops+title=moving-your-pension-abroad---what-are-the-benefits?
```

How can I ensure characters like @ ? >< don't appear in my url?

How can I avoid duplicate --- ?

Code to generate the url is as follows:

```
<a class="small magenta awesome" title="View full article" href="view-article.php?id='.$row['id'].'+category='.strtolower($row['category']).'+title='.strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$row['title'])).'">View full article &raquo;</a>
```

Pretty sure I am doing something wrong but I'm trying...

Help appreciated..

I will move on to using the mod_rewrite in apache afterwards

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate seo friendly url's with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476904/how-to-generate-seo-friendly-urls-with-php)

Comment: Your URL is already SEO friendly (yes SEs deal with it nowadays). You probably mean human readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this sweet function to generate SEO friendly URL

```
function url($url) {
        $url = preg_replace('~[^\\pL0-9_]+~u', '-', $url);
        $url = trim($url, "-");
        $url = iconv("utf-8", "us-ascii//TRANSLIT", $url);
        $url = strtolower($url);
        $url = preg_replace('~[^-a-z0-9_]+~', '', $url);
        return $url;
}
```

Comment: This function is removing information which would be good to have in the search engine instead of being removed.

Comment: UTF-8 characters not part of the us-ascii pane for example. Imagine you've got non-english text (e.g. japanese) in the title. This will so break it.

Comment: @hakre: Do you have any official resources (from Google for example) what is and what isn't good, please?

Comment: Google has lots of such documented in their help system, search for webmaster resources, e.g. http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35291&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=-1821njqh9sflg&cbrank=2

Answer (score 4):

I used to use this function

```
function SEO($input){ 
    //SEO - friendly URL String Converter    
    //ex) this is an example -> this-is-an-example
    $input = str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $input);
    $input = str_replace(array("'", "-"), "", $input); //remove single quote and dash
    $input = mb_convert_case($input, MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8"); //convert to lowercase
    $input = preg_replace("#[^a-zA-Z]+#", "-", $input); //replace everything non an with dashes
    $input = preg_replace("#(-){2,}#", "$1", $input); //replace multiple dashes with one
    $input = trim($input, "-"); //trim dashes from beginning and end of string if any
    return $input; 
}
```

For an example, you can use this by

```
echo "<title>".SEO($title)."</title>";
```